# DevOps extension doesn't prompt org owners for new scope approval

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I've added a call to the DevOps Identities API, which requires the `vso.identity` scope. When I updated my Dev extension, I received email from ADO requestion my approval for the new scope. But when I updated Prod, no approval was requested. What happened instead is an exception that has broken the extension FOR ALL USERS. I reverted the change, and now there IS an approval mail being sent. This means the extension will be broken until the owner accepts the scope change (back to what it was before!).

1. Why wasn't there an approval request?
2. What does this exception mean?

```
FS.WebApi.Exception: HostAuthorizationNotFound\n  …s-web.platform-content.es6.KX_Xwy.min.js:1:21742)', name: 'TFS.WebApi.Exception', status: 500, responseText: '{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"HostAu…kenCreateException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}', serverError: {…}, …}
(anonymous) @ build.js:2
await in (anonymous) (async)
b @ build.js:2
Ei @ build.js:2
Ha @ build.js:2
Is @ build.js:2
Ol @ build.js:2
El @ build.js:2
hl @ build.js:2
cl @ build.js:2
Jl @ build.js:2
(anonymous) @ build.js:2
bl @ build.js:2
rc @ build.js:2
t.render @ build.js:2
781 @ build.js:2
n @ build.js:2
(anonymous) @ build.js:2
(anonymous) @ build.js:2
ms.vss-web.platform-content.es6.KX_Xwy.min.js:1 
        
        
POST https://msazure.visualstudio.com/_apis/WebPlatformAuth/SessionToken 500
t.Fetch.issueRequest @ ms.vss-web.platform-content.es6.KX_Xwy.min.js:1
```